# The Play Console asks me to remove the location permission in every version

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have a special application for kids on the Play Console. I'm trying to update with the new version. However, I keep getting the following error.
I'm even trying to submit a pre-approved version from the library for review, but it shows the same error without submitting for review.

*If your target audience only includes children under 13, you should remove the request for location permission from your app.* *Please go to the app content section.*

I searched for my application code and sub-libraries, but location information is not accessed in any way.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
```

This is the case with permissions perceived for apk in the app package explorer on the Play Console.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a library you are using has the permission defined in its Manifest?

Comment: show us your manifest and dependencies

Comment: Hello, I updated

Comment: but I think this requires an adjustment on the store.

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
tools:node="remove"/>
```

add this to your manifest then try it will solve your problem.

Comment: I really tried this. However, the same error occurred without even sending the apk for review.